# How to separate elements of arrays into their base parts (IE, NSString) ~> Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

Okay. So I have an array

```
NSArray *token = [trimmedData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonnumbers];
```

I need to take this array, and separate it into it's base parts, like NSStrings. How do I get each element, and do that with it?
Sorry if it's what appears to be a simple question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not clear: token is an array containing all the split parts of the string, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: If you don't know how to do some simple things like iteration in Objective-C then may I suggest that you take some time going through some good tutorials on Objective-C. It is important that you understand the language before you go any further.

Comment: I understand iteration, I just wasn't thinking in the right places when I wrote this question. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (NSString *string in token)
{
    NSLog(@"string: '%@'", string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :-

```
int i=0;
for(i=0; i< [token count]; i++)
NSLog(@"yourString=%@",[token 
 objectAtIndex:i]);
```